# Doing "Mark Generations" in XCode Instruments from terminal

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, terminal, xcode-instruments

I'm running the command: xcrun xctrace record --template 'Allocations' --device XXXXX --attach 'iOSappName' to do the "Allocations" trace for my iOS app as part of our automation suite execution. It is able to create a trace file but I'm not able to do the "Mark Generations" to capture snapshots of the app. I looked at the man pages and there is no reference to do "generations" while the trace is recording from terminal. Is there a way to also do "Mark Generations" when running xctrace from terminal?

Comment: Please use code formatting to improve your answer. Also please elaborate on what you mean with “Mark Geberations”

Comment: When running Instruments tool from XCode application, there is a way to create snapshots of the iOS app activity by clicking on "Mark Generation". Is there a way to do the same thing when running Instruments from Terminal?